# jQuery append method in a double loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a hard time building out what is supposed to be a board with jQuery. I am strictly using jQuery to essentially append my rows and columns. I know where my logic is most likely incorrect - it is essentially within the second `forEach` loop. Here, I am creating a new div called `newSpot` and appending it to the current `row` that was created. I console logged out my selector `$(.row-${row})` and it is the correct `id` that I want to target, and my `newSpot` is a new div element. I'm not sure why it's failing to append to the current row. My only thought is that appending this way does not mean that the `row` divs actually exist yet on the DOM. Hence why it can't find any divs named so. In which case, I could just create two separate methods: one for rows, and one for columns but I'd like to figure out what's going on here first. Thanks!

```
class Board {
  constructor() {
    this.tiles = [
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ];
  }

  buildBoard() {
    this.tiles.forEach((tile, row) => {
      const newRow = $('<div></div>').addClass('row').attr('id', `row-${row}`);
      $('#snake-game-board').append(newRow);
      tile.forEach((spot, col) => {
        const newSpot = $('<div></div>').addClass('col').attr('id', `col-${col}`);
        $(`.row-${row}`).append('<div></div>');
      })
    })
  }
};

const newBoard = new Board();
newBoard.buildBoard();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
$(`#row-${row}`).
```

selects the elements whose class names are, eg, `row-2`. But the new row:

```
const newRow = $('<div></div>').addClass('row').attr('id', `row-${row}`);
```

has that as the **ID**, not as a class.

While you could fix it by changing to

```
$(`#row-${row}`)
```

It would be more elegant to just reference the already existing new row variable instead of searching through the DOM to find it again - no need for numeric-indexed IDs anymore (which are quite a code smell anyway).

You also probably wanted to append `newSpot` to the row, not an empty div. (`newSpot` is going unused at the moment).

```
this.tiles.forEach((tile) => {
    const newRow = $('<div></div>').addClass('row').appendTo('#snake-game-board');
    tile.forEach(() => {
        $('<div></div>').addClass('col').appendTo(newRow);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had the selector for `id` but I can see now that I was incorrect. Also, love the more elegant refactor - there is no need to find the row node again in the DOM when it already exists in the current iteration.